# Opengl VAO and uniforms: Handling many models in a rendering loop

Tags: opengl

Assuming I have a class which describes a model in my scene (for example a rectangle).
This class contains, most importantly the model matrix and the VAO.
When designing the drawing loop in my rendering code I now do the following (pseudo-code):

```
functon draw{
  list = getListOfMeshes() /* List containing mesh class items */
  iterate list { /* could be for example 1000 different models */
    set model matrix uniform
    bind VAO 
    draw elements
  }
}
```

I understand that this could probably be optimized to just one VAO call:

```
functon draw{
  bind VAO
  draw elements
  /* How to handle the uniforms that are different for each model?? */
}
```

Once I get many models in my scene this list iteration becomes a bottleneck. Is there an alternative way to design this rendring loop?

Comment: You can upload an array of uniforms and access them by instance id, with the command glDrawElementsInstanced. Might want to read this: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing

Comment: I understand what you try to accomplish, but I don't think this is a good idea. What if you want to reuse a given mesh multiple times in a scene, but with different sets of uniforms applied? Think about particle systems and similar situations.

Comment: @Tim: This is probably in line with what I was thinking. In this case I would only have to update the instance in the buffer array when it gets updated some place in the code? (like for example an animation loop). Would this require usage of gl_InstanceID in the vertex shader to access for example the correct model matrix?

Comment: @datenwolf: you're right, keeping the matrix in the Mesh class will not scale for that case.. I probably would need another abstraction.

Comment: You'll have to do some research on your own if you want to use my suggestion, I've never used it personally myself.

Comment: I cannot understand the question: how VAO is related to uniforms? You can share a single VAO e setup per model uniforms as needed.

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to avoid having to iterate through a list as this would be the most simple way to set a uniform in each render pass for each mesh object.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to create a model interface. Then create a list of items based on the interface. So something like

```
<code>
class interface{
    virtual render() = 0;
    virtual setUniforms()=0;
};

class object : public interface{
    render();
    setUniforms();
};
</code>
```

In this way, you can call the set uniforms function for each model you're using by the type of uniforms you want called. So things that require a normal map can have that uniform and other things that require other uniforms can have those. All the implemented uniform calls will be in the object class implementation of setUniforms(); and since their is a general interface the loop and code will execute the proper function for each object you pass into the list that satisfies the interface.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure this was what I was after. I do not see how this optimize the loop i describe?

Comment: My bad, I guess I didn't understand the question.